# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in OIDC Config Variable

Tags: angular, openid-connect

**How can i add Access-Controll-Allow-Origin header in OIDC config variable ?. Below is my sample Angular OIDC config file**

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  // Url of the Identity Provider
  issuer: 'https://steyer-identity-server.azurewebsites.net/identity',

  // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html',

  // The SPA's id. The SPA is registered with this id at the auth-server
  clientId: 'spa-demo',

  // set the scope for the permissions the client should request
  // The first three are defined by OIDC. The 4th is a usecase-specific one
  scope: 'openid profile email voucher',
}
```

**Angular code**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'flight-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
      this.configure();
    }

    private configure() {
      this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
      this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
      this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not sonething you would specify in the SPA - it typically needs to be done in these components instead, to trust requests from the SPA:

- Authorization Server
- APIs